# .Net 8 Webassembly client calling an API with cookie authentication, displaying login form

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I am new to .Net developments and I have to implement user authentication and authorization in a project. The solution has 3 projects: Backend project for RESTApi, Web (Server), and Web.Client.
I created a login page in Web.Client project which access the API endpoint to authenticate user. I followed the sample in documentation [Secure ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

```
var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("identity/login?useCookies=true", new {email,password});
```

Login Page looks like this

```
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">You logged in as @context.User.Identity?.Name.</div>
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (errors)
                    {
                        @foreach (var error in errorList)
                        {
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">@error</div>
                        }
                    }
                    <div class="flex-outer">
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">
                                Email:
                            </label>
                            <input required id="email" name="emailInput" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="email" @bind-value="email" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">
                                Password:
                            </label>
                            <input required id="password" name="passwordInput" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" @bind-value="password" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DoLoginAsync">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
```

Users can login successfully. My problem is when I access or refresh the login page after user logged in, it first display the login form (`<NotAuthorized>` part).

Then after a second or 2 (it is because `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` request the API for `identity/manage/info`), it replaced by the `<Authorized>` part.

Is there anyway to avoid showing the Login form again?
Or how can I use a loading text or a spinner here instead of the form, until the app recognizes the user is already logged in?